# Trying to link use XSL to output a HTML table from XML

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to use a `.xsl` file so that it will return a HTML table of the XML document. I have no experience with this and it is something I've not done before so it's probably this is just a simple mistake.

I have the following code for my `podcatalog.xsl`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Tranform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Pods Papers</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9ACD32">
      <th>Author</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Pages</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="pods-papers/inproceedings">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="author"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="pages"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the `podcatalog.xml` can be [found here](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~ptw/teaching/IWT/coursework/pods-papers.xml)

The error I am getting is: ***"Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed."***

Comment: If You are trying to do a xslt transform, please tell us what language are You using. Since I use C# the most, i would do this: xsltTransform.Transform(xmlReader, transformedXml); but need more info.

Comment: @ricardordz I am only trying to transform the XML data into a HTML table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
<xsl:for-each select="pods-papers/inproceedings key">
```

to:

```
<xsl:for-each select="pods-papers/inproceedings">
```

'key' is an attribute of element

Comment: I had inproceedings originally but it didn't work either. But thanks

Comment: Also: xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Tranform" -- 'Tranform' should be 'Transform'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re defining entities the wrong way (`<!ENTITY Aring  "&amp;#197;" >` should have `&` instead of `&amp;`) and, more seriously, without a DTD. It appears to be a longstanding request that we should be able to do that, but... So the problem is that your XML file has a DOCTYPE declaration that contains just entity definitions, not a document type definition.

The options appear to be:

1. Write a DTD. Some work, but might be useful for documentation purposes.
2. Replace the entity references by the characters themselves or by character references, e.g. `&Ouml;` by Ö or by `&#214;`.

Comment: The xml document wasn't written by me and is to be treated as it is. The problem was that I had written Tranform instead of Transform.